# Rails - no such table [rake db:migrate]

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having trouble with my rails database. I recently reverted to a previous commit and I'm trying to get by server and database up and running.

I have run `rake db:migrate` and 'rake db:create' which both return similar results

Any idea how to fix it?

```
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: main.users: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "index_users_on_email" ON "users" ("email")/Users/Marcus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
```

including the trace

```
$ rake db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
** Execute rails_env
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
==  AddIndexToUsersEmail: migrating ===========================================
-- add_index(:users, :email, {:unique=>true})
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
```

Let me know if I can/should supply any more information?

thanks

**More Info**

```
$rake db:reset

-- create_table("attendees", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0120s
-- create_table("competitions", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0020s
-- create_table("devices", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0019s
-- create_table("users", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0045s
-- add_index("users", ["email"], {:name=>"index_users_on_email", :unique=>true})
   -> 0.0011s
-- add_index("users", ["remember_token"], {:name=>"index_users_on_remember_token"})
   -> 0.0010s
-- initialize_schema_migrations_table()
   -> 0.0019s
-- assume_migrated_upto_version(20140210000927,     ["/Users/Marcus/Sites/Rails/rails_projects/BattleOfTheBands/db/migrate"])
   -> 0.0066s
You have 1 pending migrations:
  20140211231110 AddDeviseToUsers
Run `rake db:migrate` to update your database then try again.
```

now when I run 'rake db:migrate'

```
SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: email: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "email" varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL/Users/Marcus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create an index on a table that doesn't exist yet. I'd try doing a `rake db:reset` and see if that helps. If not, check your migrations to make sure a Users table is created before trying to put an index on one.

Comment: it seems no migration is there to create users table

Comment: added more info after "rake db:reset"

Comment: Sounds like devise is attempting to add an `email` field to your model, but it is already there.

Comment: Yeah, I think you have a duplicate devise installation migration. I would just delete the migration that's giving you trouble and try again.

Comment: The `mysql` tag should probably be changed to `sqlite`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, i was able to solve this by deleting the sqlite3 files on my box then run:

```
    rake db:create
```

then do:

```
    rake db:migrate
```

Hope this helps anyone else with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

when you are running db:reset it creates a users table and I assume you have added an email field to it or the index creation would throw an error. Then you run the missing migration to add devise. Devise includes a class AddDeviseToUsers which includes:

```
    change_table(:users) to |t|
       ## Database authenticatable
       t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
```

That's why it fails. Just remove the email field from your user migration and it will work or remove it from the devise migration.

Answer (score 0):

rake db:reset worked for me. Thanks!